# How to improve reactjs initial rendering performance on mobile?

Tags: javascript, performance, babeljs, reactjs

I have an app written in reactjs, it's pretty fast when the components are rendered, but it's too slow for it to be rendered. On computer, it takes about 2 seconds, but on mobile, it takes around 8 seconds for the page to be rendered, it's really too slow.

Is there any generic methods to improve loading time for the website?

I used chrome timeline to analyze the performance. I saw that lots of time was spent by browser.js. I was wondering if converting reactjs jsx to javascript will help.

I also saw there is a long pause before the doms are shown, I am not sure what the browser does during this time and how to solve this.

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling your project with Webpack in production mode?

Comment: converting jsx to javascript should be done while compiling the files before deployment, not in the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely pre-compile your React code for production. Also it is very important to set your `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production`. This will speed up general and initial rendering by a lot (even more so for server-side rendering).
You could use the browserify plugin `envify` for this, or the corresponding webpack plugin (depending on your stack).

Also I recommend this conference talk, which includes lots of other minor/major rendering speed-ups: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnpfGy7q96U

Comment: From the video you shared, I think just using minified version of reactjs will be enough and we don't even need to set the NODE_ENV. You really helped, bro.